# What is the filename of "New Messages Sound"?

Tags: mail.app, audio

I'm looking for the file which Mail plays when a message comes in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's located in the Resources folder inside Mail.app. Assuming you've left Mail.app in its default installed location, the path is:

```
/Applications/Mail.app/Contents/Resources/New\ Mail.aiff
```